# Looking for a way to prevent users from opening a text file that i transfer from android to PC

Tags: android, file, text-files

Looking for a way to prevent users from opening a text file that i transfer from android to PC

Through DropBox.

is convert the text file to bin file Will do the job ?

can i get any sample code in java (for android) that convert text file to bin file ?

i try this but dont work:

```
Reading the file:

File queryImg = new File(ImagePath);
int imageLen = (int)queryImg.length();
byte [] imgData = new byte[imageLen];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(queryImg);
fis.read(imgData);


Writing the file:

FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("/MyPath/xx.bin"));
f.write(imgData);
f.flush();
f.close();
```

Comment: This isn't the place to say "Can I get sample code" and expect people to just give you the code, you need to try something and provide code that people can help resolve issues with. With regard to your problem however, instead of blocking opening, why not just encrypt it?

Comment: What is a "bin file"? What does "don't work" mean?

Comment: i dont know how to insert my text line and convert it to bin, for example in the code - how to insert text to imgData as bin ?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand the question, I'd suggest either changing file extension from .txt to otherwise nonexistent extension of your choice (.gldsft or something like that), encrypting, or not going with text file at all.